# Read file of internal storage failed, error is "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)"

Tags: android, performance

Codes are below

```
...
File newFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "time.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newFile.toString());
show_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
....
```

Get errors are below

```
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/data/user/0/com.example.flover.testdemo/files/time.jpg: 
open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Android device version is 6.0, I couldn't figure out why this error occurred, according to google api doc, app has right to access to files which belong to itself.
If anyone gets answers, please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private Context mContext=YourActivity.this;

private static final int REQUEST = 112;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
    if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST );
    } else {
        createFile();
    }
} else {
     createFile();
}
```

get Permissions Result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    createFile();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to write in your storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

check permissions  for marshmallow

```
private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

createFile Function:

```
public void createFile()
{
    File newFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "time.jpg");
    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(newFile.toString());
    show_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Comment: Try and no luck, dude, still get same error. PS. that file I want to read is stored in internal storage. So I don't think using permissions like you do will fit here.